# How to optimized input parameters?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for the right machine approach to optimize about five program parameters. What I have is a growing table with past results.

Which machine learning method could serve well in this scenario?

EDIT:

The training data is a simple table:

Time | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | Time Elapsed

There are about 200k rows and steady growing. The optimization is to minimize "Time elapsed" which is also dependent on other factors than the parameters but the parameters are the biggest influence in every sample taken.

I am looking for recommendable types of neural networks (or other methods). I thought about back propagation or maybe PSO but I lack the experience (only ever coded a GA) to decide where to start.

Comment: That depends on results you want, the shape and connectivity of the data, the interdependence of the parameters, your definition of "optimum", and a variety of other factors.  Please describe the problem in detail, especially with respect to the research you've already done on the matter, and repost with a specific, answerable question.

Comment: @Prune: Is the added information of any value? I know the question is still vague, but I am also looking for vague answers, not recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a big help.  Do note that StackOverflow is defined as a place for specific questions.  However, this one, I think, is straightforward enough.

I don't know how much help this might be; I'm trying to start simply.

You have a large enough data base to build a prediction model; I'd start with a logistic regression and see how that does in predicting its own training data.  Do you have ANN software that lets you "seed" the learning with such a model?  That would get you the best of both worlds.

If the incoming data will eventually dominate the initial data (say, growing at least 10x), then I suggest a neural network, even if you have to start from scratch.  Does the output depend on each input continuously?  In other words, does a small change in any input make only a small change in the output -- or are there large leaps at some data values?  If the changes are continuous, then your thought of back propagation should work best.

Do you have a choice of computation methods?  The classic gradient descent is the place to start.  If it isn't flexible enough for the actual data, then you can try moving to something logistic or Gaussian.

Have you decided on your error function (cost function) for training?  least square is a classic choice, but the appropriate function depends on your desired training "shape": do you have to fit "normal" cases with great precision?  do you need a particularly smooth brane (hyperplane)?  Can you tolerate being much farther off for outliers?

Fortunately, you have a large amount of data for a handful of inputs; this gives you a lot of good room to experiment.  Don't be afraid to add extra terms in the early experiments.  For instance, you can load down a gradient descent with a lot of variations for each variable: x, x^2, x^3, sqrt(x), ln(x), Atan(x), etc.

Comment: thanks a lot, this encourages me to code an ANN using back propagation (maybe PSO). I thought about maybe using a GA for the free parameters, does that sound like a reasonable idea? About the computations, I will have to rely to the "all purpose" methods and maybe optimize from there. One thing that I keep wrapping my head around is that I don't want to predict the "time elapsed" output but I want to predict which input parameters are good parameters to get feasibly low "time elapsed" results (in an continuously changing environment).